# No debugging symbols found in ./d8

Tags: macos, gdb, v8

1. run v8's d8 command, prompt (No debugging symbols found in ./d8). after executing the command, exit the program.
2. here is a hint of the code.

```
➜  x64.debug git:(e47af00448) ✗ gdb ./d8     // this                                                                                      
GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./d8...

warning: `/Users/didi/Desktop/source/test/v8/v8/out/x64.debug/obj/d8/async-hooks-wrapper.o': file time stamp mismatch.

warning: `/Users/didi/Desktop/source/test/v8/v8/out/x64.debug/obj/d8/d8-console.o': file time stamp mismatch.

warning: `/Users/didi/Desktop/source/test/v8/v8/out/x64.debug/obj/d8/d8-js.o': file time stamp mismatch.

warning: `/Users/didi/Desktop/source/test/v8/v8/out/x64.debug/obj/d8/d8-platforms.o': file time stamp mismatch.

warning: `/Users/didi/Desktop/source/test/v8/v8/out/x64.debug/obj/d8/d8-posix.o': file time stamp mismatch.

warning: `/Users/didi/Desktop/source/test/v8/v8/out/x64.debug/obj/d8/d8-test.o': file time stamp mismatch.

warning: `/Users/didi/Desktop/source/test/v8/v8/out/x64.debug/obj/d8/d8.o': file time stamp mismatch.
(No debugging symbols found in ./d8)
```

3. expect

can be used normally.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled `d8` with debug information?

Comment: yes, d8 produced using the gm x64.release command.

Comment: I'd be surprised if a release build includes debug information.  Try `file d8`, check the output includes `with debug_info`.  If that text is missing from the output of `file` then you don't have debug information (as GDB is telling you).

Comment: I run `file d8` and it prompts: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64.

Comment: After tossing for a few days, I haven't found the reason, emmm

Comment: You have not compiled `d8` with debug information.  Investigate your build system to understand why this might be.  I would suggest not trying to create a release build as that is most likely to have debug information stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

> d8 produced using the `gm x64.release` command

Release builds don't have debugging information. Try `gm x64.debug`.

That said, the error message you posted does mention `.../out/x64.debug/obj/...`, so it's not clear how you actually built. Are you maybe trying to force one build's debugging information into another build's GDB session? That isn't going to work.

`file time stamp mismatch` sounds like recompiling might fix it, have you tried that?

Also, the usual workflow is to remain in the main checkout directory, and invoke d8 as `gdb -args out/x64.debug/d8 ...`. If that was the problem, the error would likely look different though.

Another shot in the dark: try LLDB, which may work better on MacOS.

Comment: I re-executed `gm x64.debug`, but it still doesn't work, and there are other error messages, click [here] (https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg/issues/1361). I will use `LLDB` to solve it.

Comment: @user12591580 Well, recursion bugs in pwndbg are completely unrelated to having debugging symbols in V8 builds.